# OpenLayers Scale Line not showing on the map

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to generate a scale line on my map using `ScaleLine` but it is not showing on the map.

```
//Scale
import {defaults as defaultControls, ScaleLine} from 'ol/control';

map = new Map({
      target: 'map-container',
      controls: defaultControls().extend([
        new ScaleLine()
      ]),
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM()
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [114.190750, 22.339914],
        zoom: 12,
        minZoom: 12,
      }),
    });
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly here https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-wgs84-o5kg1  Have you included the css?

Comment: i just checked, the code is the same it seems like its not working for me for some reason.

Comment: <div class="ol-scale-line-inner" style="width: 109px;">2 km</div>

The value here is changing but the map does not have the scale line. What could be the issue ?

Comment: maybe you have some css overriding the default?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe openLayers css for scaling is not imported, or overwritten. try importing this style into your header and see if it worked.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```